# How to execute PostgreSQL slash methods on ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am using Rails 4. I am trying to list all PostgreSQL databases with '\l' using 'execute' method from ActiveRecord. Connection is correctly established.

```
p = ActiveRecord::Tasks::PostgreSQLDatabaseTasks.new(configuration)
p.send 'establish_master_connection'
p.connection.execute('\l')
```

Here is the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "l"
```

When I use 'no slash' method it works fine

```
connection.execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS NOTHING")
=> #<PG::Result:0xc5e6094 status=PGRES_COMMAND_OK ntuples=0 nfields=0 cmd_tuples=0>
```

Any idea?

Comment: `\l` is not a SQL statement, it's a command specific to `psql`. The only "interface" through which you can run that is `psql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Commands beginning with `\` are meta commands implemented by the psql shell itself - the database server itself doesn't know what they mean.

In the particular case of the commands listing various things, this normally boils down to querying tables in pg_catalog e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_database
```

for databases

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_table
```

for tables. These are documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalogs.html)

Comment: Is there a way to list databases then?

Comment: @PiotrBrudny You need to do the query that psql was doing for you - i've given some examples